# Convert CString to NSUTF16encoded NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, cstring

I have a cstring, which I am able to convert into a NSUTF8 NSString like this

```
NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:cstring];
```

however I was wondering if there is a way to convert it into a UTF16String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use NSString's `stringWithCString:encoding`

```
NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithCString:cstring encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
```

Or if you wish to stick with the alloc/init format use:

```
NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:cstring encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
```

Comment: nope its still sweet.. **stringWithCString** is depricated not **stringWithCString:encoding:**  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: no worries... can I ask you one last question, I have used your example but now for some reason my answer is coming back in Chinese or something.... even though if i log my cstring its english.. and makes sense... lol

Comment: @HurkNburkS Sorry, but I couldn't tell you why that's happening. I'm not very familiar with UTF16, but my first thought would be to make sure your cString is in fact UTF16 encoded.

Comment: The encoding is not the encoding that you will use for NSString, NSString doesn't care.  It will always store its data UTF16.  The encoding variable is the encoding that your c-string is stored as, because this info is not available, it is just an array of chars.  NSString needs to know how to read it, not how to store it.

Comment: okay I have figured out why this is happening like @borrrden has said the NSString dosnt care, I have copied a byte array that was perviously stored as UTF8 into a cstring... the c string copies each byte as a character. this works fine for every english character but if I have a forigen character which normally takes two bytes its getting stored as two characters or more... which is stuffing up my NSString later on.. what I need to figure out how to do is to save the bytes straight to a NSString with UTF8 encoding... so that i get the bytes back to their normal state.

Comment: Yes, it will just be a long list of bytes...but that doesn't matter if it was encoded correctly, and you use the same encoding when you put it into an NSString.  UTF8 can have multibyte characters.